# File watcher is not doing anything for coping files to FTP

Tags: powershell, winscp

When I run the below script, nothing happens for uploading arriving files to FTP

I just get this in poweschell

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SCRIPT> .\NEWR4.PS1
Loaded WinSCP .NET assembly
Enter your FTP username: ****
Enter your FTP password: ********
Enter the UNC path of the source directory: \HOPE5\MEDIA
Session options set up
Session and debug log paths set
Connected to FTP server
File watcher set up

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command

---

1      f1cabfda-26c...                 NotStarted    False                                 ...
File watcher event registered

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
Write-Host "Loaded WinSCP .NET assembly"

# Prompt for username and password
$UserName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your FTP username'
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your FTP password' -AsSecureString

# Prompt for source directory
$SourceDirectory = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the UNC path of the source directory'

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.host.com"
    UserName = $UserName
    Password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password))
}
Write-Host "Session options set up"

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

# Set session and debug log paths
$session.SessionLogPath = "C:\temp\WinSCP.log"
$session.DebugLogPath = "C:\temp\WinSCP-debug.log"
Write-Host "Session and debug log paths set"

try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    Write-Host "Connected to FTP server"

    # Watcher
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = $SourceDirectory
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
    Write-Host "File watcher set up"

    $action = { 
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($path)
        if ($extension -eq ".mxf" -or $extension -eq ".mp4" -or $extension -eq ".xml" -or $extension -eq ".oseq") {
            if ($path -notlike "*.$TMP") {
                try {
                    # Check if file is still growing
                    $size = (Get-Item $path).Length
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
                    $newSize = (Get-Item $path).Length
                    if ($size -eq $newSize) {
                        # Check if file is newer than 1 day
                        $creationTime = (Get-Item $path).CreationTime
                        $timeDifference = New-TimeSpan -Start $creationTime -End (Get-Date)
                        if ($timeDifference.TotalDays -le 1) {
                            # Check if remote directory exists
                            $remotePath = "/$(Split-Path $path -Leaf)"
                            if (-not $session.FileExists($remotePath)) {
                                # Create remote directory
                                $session.CreateDirectory($remotePath)
                                Write-Host ("Created remote directory {0}" -f $remotePath)
                            }

                            # Upload files
                            Write-Host ("Attempting to upload file {0}" -f $path)
                            $transferResult = $session.PutFiles($path, $remotePath)

                            # Throw on any error
                            $transferResult.Check()

                            # Print results
                            foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers) {
                                Write-Host ("Upload of {0} succeeded" -f $transfer.FileName)
                                Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\WinSCP-success.log" -Value ("Upload of {0} succeeded" -f $transfer.FileName)
                            }
                        } else {
                            Write-Host ("File {0} is older than 1 day, skipping this round" -f $path)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Write-Host ("File {0} is still growing, skipping this round" -f $path)
                    }
                } catch {
                    Write-Host ("Error: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                    Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\WinSCP-error.log" -Value ("Error: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                    if ($_.Exception.InnerException -ne $null) {
                        Write-Host ("Inner Exception: {0}" -f $_.Exception.InnerException.Message)
                        Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\WinSCP-error.log" -Value ("Inner Exception: {0}" -f $_.Exception.InnerException.Message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Write-Host "File watcher event registered"
    while ($true) { sleep 5 }
} finally {
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
    Write-Host "Disconnected from FTP server"
}
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and clarify what the problem is. Also, please add relevant tags.

Comment: We need [mcve]. It seems that you have a problem with "file watcher". So I guess that none of the FTP code is really relevant to the problem. Or is it?